# Regex website with exactly one subfolder and nothing else after

Tags: c#, regex, url

Can anyone please help with the correct regex pattern?
Basically I want to capture all the strings that have exactly only one subfolder and nothing else after (except maybe a forward slash).

This is my regex but it does not match everything:

```
Regex Pattern: http(s)?:\/\/(.*).(.*)/(\w-)*\b
```

Strings to match (what I wanted to match are with arrows):

```
    http://test.org/
==> http://test.org/SubFolder1             
    http://test.org/SubFolder1?Query=Test
    http://test.org/SubFolder1/SubFolder2
    http://test.org/SubFolder1/SubFolder2?Query=Test
    http://www.test.org/
==> http://www.test.org/SubFolder1  
    http://www.test.org/SubFolder1?Query=Test
    http://www.org/SubFolder1/SubFolder2
    http://www.org/SubFolder1/SubFolder2?Query=Test
    www.test.org/
==> www.test.org/SubFolder1  
    www.test.org/SubFolder1?Query=Test
    www.org/SubFolder1/SubFolder2
    www.org/SubFolder1/SubFolder2?Query=Test
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regexr I was able to work something out.  Many times you aren't going to be able to google your exact solution so you should to spend some time trying to understand how to write regex for your unique needs.

```
(https?:\/\/)?\w+\.+[\w\.]*\/[\w-]+$
```

- optional https
- 1 or more letters
- 1 or more dots
- any number of letters or dots
- a slash (I escaped it here, you didn't have it escaped - sometimes its needed)
- 1 or more letters or hyphens (you had the hyphen in yours)
- end of line

I created a regexr [here](https://regexr.com/3r7fe) which explains the solution in a very graphical way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Regex, just use the built in [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) and [UriBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/azure/system.uribuilder(v=vs.85).aspx) class(es):

First make a method to determine if the input string is a match:

```
public static bool IsMatch(string url)
{
    Uri uri = new UriBuilder(url).Uri;
    return uri.Segments.Length == 2 && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.Query);
}
```

Then you can just filter your list using LINQ:

```
var matchedUrls = urls.Where(IsMatch);
```

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3jMF8)